# How to store images in an array when image is on load

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm still new to Javascript. I have this array of images and all I want is to store it to a new array when it is onload. If it's not(onerror), it will not be stored to that new array. I already have this code wherein it shows new array that has thesame image values.

```
var myarray=[];

for (var i=0; i < imagesarray.length; i++) {

    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function () {
        console.log("Image loaded !");
        myarray.push(image.src);
    }
    image.onerror = function () {

        console.log("Cannot load image");
    }
    image.src = imagesarray[i].photo;
}

console.log(myarray);
```

Please help. Thank you. :)

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Comment: Oh! I see: myarray is empty when you call `console.log(myarray)`

Comment: It's not empty. It shows values that are thesame.

Comment: OK. try to declare your image variable with a let: `let image = new Image();`

Comment: or simply push this.src: `myarray.push(this.src);`

Comment: Should'nt it be `myarray.push(imagesarray[i].src);` instead of `myarray.push(image.src);` ?!

Comment: OH MY GOD! with just that?! It really helps! It doesn't show thesame values anymore. Thank you so much, Maurice! :D

Comment: @chsdk no: i would be greater than the length of the array

Comment: I've used your suggestion, the let image= new Image(); one . thank you1million times. :D

Comment: @QueenElizabeth You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Maurice Perry.

let image= new Image() works!

This solves my problem.